# Sort an array of objects based on a numeric key given as String values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array with key-value pairs, array columns are id and name. I want to sort this array by id.

The id column value is of type string type but I want to sort them as numeric values also should work on IE

Here is my code:

```js
var items = [{
    "id": "165",
    "name": "a"
  },
  {
    "id": "236",
    "name": "c"
  },
  {
    "id": "376",
    "name": "b"
  },
  {
    "id": "253",
    "name": "f"
  },
  {
    "id": "235",
    "name": "e"
  },
  {
    "id": "24",
    "name": "d"
  },
  {
    "id": "26",
    "name": "d"
  }
];

console.log(items.sort((a, b) => Number(a.ID) - Number(b.ID)))
```

Though the order does change it doesn't change as expected also in IE an error is thrown.

Comment: Have you tried anything.  If so, please post your code.  Stack Overflow is not a "write code for me" service.

Comment: www.google.com for real now.. This kind of question is asked like EVERY day here, every goddamn day, you can surely find an answer in one of the previous ones

Comment: You can use sort function. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: item.sort((a, b) => Number(a.ID) - Number(b.ID)) I used but its not working on IE11. @Archer

Comment: @Anshul "it's not working" is not very helpful. What isn't working? Please add more details to your question

Comment: I am using angular 1 and I get a array of items shown above and want to show these items on UI according to ID column I use many codes using arrow (=> )for it but not working on IE11 only @Luca

Answer (score 2):

Now you can do it with pure JS, using the sort method..

```js
var items = [
  {
    "id": "165",
    "name": "a"
  },
  {
    "id": "236",
    "name": "c"
  },
  {
    "id": "376",
    "name": "b"
  },
  {
    "id": "253",
    "name": "f"
  },
  {
    "id": "235",
    "name": "e"
  },
  {
    "id": "24",
    "name": "d"
  },
  {
    "id": "26",
    "name": "d"
  }
];

items.sort((a,b)=>+a.id>+b.id);
console.log(items);
```

Comment: That's a sick one liner :)

Comment: Arrow functions don't work in IE

Comment: You are right arrow not working on IE @Andrew Bone

Comment: Then don't use Arrow functions, they aren't needed here

Comment: `items.sort(function(a, b){return +(a.id)>+(b.id)})` should work in IE

Comment: @Luca you are correct but this answer has one and it's where the OP is struggling

Comment: You can try separating the compare function as :      


`function compare(first, second) {
     
 };

items.sort(compare);`

Comment: item.sort(function (a, b) { return parseInt(a.id) - parseInt(b.id) }) this is working for all browsers

Comment: @Andrew Bone, Luca, bassxzero, Harunur Rashid, Thanks for your valuable suggetions